# MVC Model can't convert received string to Double or Decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just deployed my application to the server. For some odd reason the server cannot seem to convert the received string value (on a model) into a Double or Decimal, the ModelState ends up being invalid. Any idea why? Everything works just fine on my local PC...

Please help.

Comment: Could be a culture issue. Is the value in the correct format to match the server culture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure web.config at system.web/globalization/@culture to use a culture of your choosing, so that culture isnt autoconfigured.